# Connect delta lake table for CRUD operation in azure ADLS GEN2 path using only pure java code

Tags: java, azure, delta-lake

I am trying to connect using DSR method but getting following error while reading snapshot parquet files on azure adlsgen2 path.
I have added some maven dependencies: Ex. hadoop-client,hadoop-azure,parquet-hadoop,scala-library,spark-core_2.12

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/java8/JFunction0$mcJ$sp
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.SnapshotManagement.getLogSegmentForVersion(SnapshotManagement.scala:102)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.SnapshotManagement.getLogSegmentForVersion$(SnapshotManagement.scala:96)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.DeltaLogImpl.getLogSegmentForVersion(DeltaLogImpl.scala:32)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.SnapshotManagement.getSnapshotAtInit(SnapshotManagement.scala:201)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.SnapshotManagement.$init$(SnapshotManagement.scala:35)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.DeltaLogImpl.<init>(DeltaLogImpl.scala:36)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.DeltaLogImpl$.apply(DeltaLogImpl.scala:83)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.DeltaLogImpl$.forTable(DeltaLogImpl.scala:72)
    at io.delta.standalone.internal.DeltaLogImpl.forTable(DeltaLogImpl.scala)
    at io.delta.standalone.DeltaLog.forTable(DeltaLog.java:86)
    at com.example.demo.DeltaLakeApplication.main(DeltaLakeApplication.java:38)
```

Comment: what Spark version? What delta version? It looks like you have missing dependencies because of the error: `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: I have added following maven dependencies so please check and let us know if any version mismatch or required dependency   and also if you know how connect delta lake table in azure adlsgen2 using jdbc from pure java code   :                             delta-standalone_2.12(v0.2.0), hadoop-client(v3.2.1),hadoop-azure(v3.2.1),parquet-hadoop(v1.10.0),scala-library(2.11.12), spark-core_2.12(v2.4.3),

Comment: Remove `scala-library(2.11.12)` it's not compatible with `spark-core_2.12`. Upgrade delta to the 0.6.1 that is latest supported for Spark 2.4.x. Also hadoop version may not be compatible with your Spark version. But the main question - do you really need to use old versions of Spark, etc.?